# Riddle - not on Stack Exchange

Tags: riddle, word

Follow this to find the answer;
Everyone knows it, but few see it.
Stuck between a pair of seers,
But it cannot prophesy at all.

Not on Stack Exchange,
Only in real life.
You've heard it once,
Now write it down.

---

What is being referred to in this riddle? Please explain how your answer fits all the clues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a

> nose

Follow this to find the answer;

> The expression "follow your nose"

Everyone knows it, but few see it.

> Homophone of "knows", you know it's there but don't see it

Stuck between a pair of seers,

> between your eyes

But it cannot prophesy at all.

> not sure, maybe just double-meaning on "seers"

Not on Stack Exchange,

> acronym for NOSE

Only in real life.

> online, you're virtual and don't have a body?

You've heard it once,

> refers to the knows/nose homophone

Comment: Correct! Was it too easy?

Comment: The penultimate line also refers to the homophone you spotted.

Comment: @randal'thor Well, I finally got a riddle, so I'm happy about the difficulty! Though if a dilettante like me can get it, it's probably easy for hardcore riddlers.

Comment: @randal'thor not that easy, I wasn't close... unfortunately I went a step too far with the "pair of seers" and was thinking about IxxxxI